# Omni-Channel: Apex trigger is not being called while a case is accepted via omni-channel notification

Tags: apex, trigger, case, omnichannel

I have a custom object called Action__c which has a lookup relationship to Case and I have written a trigger to update the owner of the Action the same time a case ownership changes. The functionality works perfectly when I test it out of the service console by manually changing the case owner it updates the related Action owners too. But when I run the same scenario on service console it isn't working and only when I switched on the debug log I realised the trigger itself is not being called. Can anyone suggest me a work around please ?

Answer (score 1):

Till now this feature is not provided by Salesforce.
Because when the omni-channel feature was built salesforce people wanted to make sure that their customers didn't run into any recursive loops from workflow rules or apex triggers firing. (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000228601&language=en_US)